# How can I call unittest.assertRaisesRegex from code that supports both Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In Python 3.2, `unittest.assertRaisesRegexp` was renamed to `unittest.assertRaisesRegex`. How can I call this functionality,  while preserving the existing syntax, from code that must support both Python 2 and 3? I would rather avoid changing calls like `self.assertRaisesRegexp('ValueError', 'foo')` into calls to `myAssertRaisesRegex(self, 'ValueError', 'foo')`. My favorite approach would be one that lets me use the Python 3 name going forward, since we will eventually drop Python 2 support. As second-best, I'm okay with using syntax like `self.assertRaisesRegexSpecial('ValueError', 'foo')` -- in other words, coming up with a name of my own that will work with both Python 2 and 3 without requiring a change in syntax.

The function is a class method, so I can't follow the pattern of what is commonly done for `range`/`xrange`:

```
try:
    xrange
except NameError:
    range = xrange

# Now range can be used from this point on in the code.
```

Nor, as far as I can tell, can I modify the class. I know how to determine whether `unittest.assertRaisesRegex` exists in the version of Python I'm using, namely:

`hasattr(unittest.TestCase, 'assertRaisesRegexp')`

What's the right way to add an attribute to the existing unittest that maps to `assertRaisesRegexp` for Python 2 but to `assertRaisesRegex` for Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise, it turned out that nothing stops me from calling `setattr` on `unittest.TestCase` even though the class is from the standard Python library. Thus, I can do this:

```
if not hasattr(unittest.TestCase, 'assertRaisesRegex'):
    setattr(unittest.TestCase, 'assertRaisesRegex', unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp)
```